# how to add a dropdown field to openerp module

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I am using openerp 7. I have created a module with some fields . Now I need to declare dropdown fields to add some additional features. Please give me some hint to do this

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

For drop down list, you can use selection field.
for example

```
'type': fields.selection([('a','Type A'),('b', 'Type B')],'Type')
```

You can want to show a many2one field as selection, for example, companies, in the view add widget="selection"

```
<field name="company_id" widget="selection">
```

Comment: I have edited my code in xml as well as .py file, but Im getting openerp server error

Comment: now I am receiving some other error.                                                                                                                                     ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!

Comment: add in the question it self if its okey, otherwise send me to omalbastin@gmail.com

Comment: Thanx it worked, is there any way that we declare checkable fields and then admin can set only the checked  field to the form . Can this be done .? Any hint plz

Comment: look I want to create some fields that admin can activate or deactivate whenever he wants. if there are 10 fields but admin want to check on 5 to make that available. Get it ? Can this be done ?

Comment: add a new group and specify this group for the fields in xml. if user belong to this group, then only he/she will be able to see it